# Is there a difference between a pointer parameter and an array parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, types

`void method(double *v)`

`void method(double v[5])`

Is there any difference between these two?

Is the second one more specific, as in `v` being constrained to 5 elements in length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays when declared as parameter types, decay to the pointer types. In your example,

```
void method(double v[5]);
```

Here `5` doesn't play any role at all, it is so *insignificant* that you *may omit* it altogether, and write this instead:

```
void method(double v[]);
```

which is exactly same as the previous declaration. Since it decays into pointer, so the above two are exactly same as:

```
void method(double *v); //because array decays to pointer, anyway
```

That is, all the following are declarations of the same function:

```
void method(double v[5]); //ok : declaration 
void method(double v[]);  //ok : redeclaration of the above
void method(double *v);   //ok : redeclaration of the above
```

ALL are exactly same. No difference at all.

Note that the following is different however:

```
void f(double (&v)[5]);
```

It declares a function which can take array of doubles of size **exactly** `5`. If you pass array of any other size (or if you pass pointers), it will give compilation error!

Answer (score 4):

No and no.

When in function arguments, they are the same, the compiler treats the argument `double v[5]` as a pointer. The size `5` is ignored, it's at most a signal for the programmer.

> #### C++ 11 §8.3.5 Functions *Section 3*
>
> [ ... ] After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`,” respectively.

Comment: Except that you can get the length of the array in the second case, I think? And what happens if you pass in a double[6]? I'd expect the first case to work, but the second to generate an error.

Comment: @DavidLively You mean inside the function? No, you can't, it's a pointer to the compiler.

Comment: An array[5] is considered different from an array[10] for compiler checks on function argument lists.

Comment: Bizarre - I'd expect this to be passed by value, but my quick test app shows that is not the case.

Comment: @DavidLively: See my answer. It explains further.